# Convert a function to delegate

Tags: function, delegates, d

I have a property that accepts a delegate: [`http.onReceiveHeader = (in char\[\] key, in char\[\] value) { }`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_net_curl.html#HTTP). I want to use a separed function instead of, e.g:

```
void do_something(char[] key, char[] value)
{
}

http.onReceiveHeader = do_something;
```

it's possible do it in D?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [`toDelegate`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_functional.html#toDelegate) function in [`std.functional`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_functional.html).

So this should work:

```
http.onReceiveHeader = toDelegate(do_something);
```

Comment: it's not working with all functions. e.g, I tried to do equivalent with the `.onReceive` property. But I get an error: `Error: not a property client.onReceive` where `client` is a `HTTP()` struct instance,and the `onReceive` property is defined as the following: `client.onReceive = toDelegate(&_Html);` and the function:`private ulong _Html(ubyte[] data)
  {
    body ~= to!string(data);
    return data.length;
  }` I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: (it's a replacement to 'client.onReceive = (ubyte[] data) { body ~= to!string(data); return data.length; };` that works fine.